# Mount space on Ubuntu

Tags: partition, gparted

I have a sda7, which is where the OS was installed. It has the file system of ext4 with 8GB free of 25GB (with a key also). Aside from that I also has a sda4 of type ntfs which was my old data partition in Windows. I've taken about 20GB/102GB from it in order to extend sda7. But it seems that I can neither extend nor shrink the sda7, so the 20GB is useless. Is there any way to extend the sda7 WITH and/or WITHOUT using an USB?

I  used GParted but haven't applied the operations yet

Comment: "_I've followed all instruction on the Internet_" there is absolutely no way you've followed all instructions on the Internet. You may have followed one or two... which ones? How did you use `gparted` - what did you ask it to do?

Comment: edit your question and include the output of 'sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda' then re-phrase your question refering to the partitions listed in the output. tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question without more information, but most likely the case is clear: As you pointed out, sda7 is the partition your system is installed on. You're probably running gparted from within that system now, so the partition is mounted and needed to run the system. Therefore you can't modify sda7, because you can't modify an ext4 filesystem while it's in use. That is called "online resizing" and is only supported by very few filesystems. You have to use gparted from another boot medium, e.g. a live disc, to resize your system partition while it is not mounted.

Comment: Is it also possible when I run GParted on an USB?

Comment: Yes, that's possible as well. The only important thing is, that the partition you want to resize is not mounted. Which it has to be, if you're running your system from it.